# Firebase - bidirectional communication between users in a 2 player game

Tags: firebase

It seems like there are two choices with firebase for sending and receiving "moves" between players in a 'serverless' two player game.  I could either use FCM and firebase cloud functions to send and send receive messages between the players,

i.e. player 1 calls a cloud function to communicate a "move" and the function calls FCM to send a message to the opponent a "move" was initiated by the other player.

or I could have both players observe the  "game state" document in firestore, so that each player calls a cloud function to update the game state, and the other player is notified about the opponents move when the observer of the "game state" document registers a change in the document.

Neither of these approaches seems ideal fo the purpose, using the game state document seems a little easier perhaps could be because I understand firestore better than FCM.
just wondering what the "best practice" is for handling this kind of bilateral signalling between two users.  (I guess the same basic question would arise in trying to build a "chat function" between two users on an web app.  (the app itself is built in Angular) and just uses local code, a few cloud functions and a firestore, but no dedicated server.

Comment: Note for whoever closed this -- the question was sufficiently focused for Tarik Huber to give me exactly the answer I was looking for.  The question does in fact focus on one problem, which is whether Firebase Cloud Message or whether an obseerver on a database is the better method for achieving peer-to-peer communication.  I am sure I am not the only one who faces these kinds of architectural choices in building apps and it seems a disservice to close a question like for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Firebase for this I would recommend to use the realtimedatabase. The FCM can have some lag when delivering and it depends on multiple stuff you can't control like battery status, etc. (the OS decidec more when to get new messages). By using the realtime database you are in control when it happens. I would not use Firestore because you are charged there for reads and writes and you will probably have a lot of them.